# Calling a member-function by std::function with reference to the object type as first parameter

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, std-function

When using `std::function` to call a non-static member-function, we can pass either the object pointer or the object reference as the first parameter:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    void bar() const { std::cout << "Foo::bar called "<< std::endl; }
};
 
int main() {
    Foo foo;

    // version1: pass the object pointer
    std::function<void(Foo*)> call_bar_by_pointer = &Foo::bar;
    call_bar_by_pointer(&foo);

    // or, version2: pass the object reference
    std::function<void(Foo&)> call_bar_by_reference = &Foo::bar;
    call_bar_by_reference(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

In my previous understanding, the non-static member-function essentially has the object pointer as the first argument implicitly. So when it comes to `std::function` for calling a non-static member-function, I also expect the first parameter in the parameter list to be the pointer to the object type (i.e., version1).

Can someone kindly explain **why the reference type (i.e., version2) is also supported here, and how it works**?

Comment: It is not a language feature, e.g. neither of `void(*call_bar_by_pointer)(Foo*) = &Foo::bar; void(*call_bar_by_reference)(Foo&) = &Foo::bar;`  would compile. Custom class implementation could [invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke#Possible_implementation) anything that looks reasonable and useful, e.g. you can write Function template implementation that would accept and invoke Foo**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` can be used for any [callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable).

It uses the *INVOKE* definition, specifically:

> *INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)* is defined as follows:
>
> - if f is a pointer to member function of class T:
>
>   - (1) if `std::is_base_of<T, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(t1)>>::value` is `true`, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)`
>   - (2) otherwise, [...] (`std::reference_wrapper` specialization)
>   - (3) otherwise, if t1 does not satisfy the previous items, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)`.

Point (1) works when `t1` is a simple value or a reference, and point (3) works when `t1` is a pointer (could be a smart pointer too).

This is just how `std::function` (and anything using [*INVOKE*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke#Possible_implementation)) is implemented. Without it, you cannot use the same syntax, you must use the pointer-to-member operator:

```
using BarType = void (Foo::*)() const;
BarType normal_function_pointer = &Foo::bar;
(foo.*normal_function_pointer)();
```

Note that `std::function` even works with `std::reference_wrapper` (point (2)), and it could work with other things, like double pointers, but that's just not implemented (and probably not useful).